# SQL - Delete repeated rows in table

Tags: sql, combinations

I need to delete the repeated row-

I have this table-

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp13P.png)
The result that I need-

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqoWo.png)

*keep only one combination of 2 column (the order is not important)

Thanks! (:

Comment: Which database are you using?  There are different approaches with each...

Comment: If columns are related/similar consider to normalize your table. You could create another table that has one record for every column and links to this main table via foreign-key. Then you could `GROUP BY FK_Col,Value` or simply with `DISTINCT FK_Col,Value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method that should be efficient:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 <= col2
union all
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 > col2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col2 and t2.col2 = t.col1);
```

Note:  This is a SQL `select` statement, so it does not *delete* rows in the table.  You seem to want the results from a query, not to modify the underlying table.

Comment: Sorry @Gordon I didn't intend to choose the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the spec "keep only one combination of 2 column, [column] order not important":

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM t
WHERE col1 <= col2
UNION
SELECT col2, col1
FROM t
WHERE col1 > col2;
```